# WinForms DataGridView Export to HTML with Cell Colors

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview and I change some of its rows according to some conditions (using CellFormatting event). That works fine. I need to implement a save as HTML (or PDF) functionality. I loop through its rows and columns and generate the HTML code, it works. But I also need to retain row coloring.

I'm trying to access a specific cell's back color using the following code in the loop:

```
gridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor
```

but it always returns 0.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor.Name`

Will get the name of the colour

`gridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor.R`

`gridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor.G`

`gridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor.B`

Will get the RGB values

Comment: Yes, but BackColor.Name returns "0". R, G and B properties are also 0, so when I try to convert RGB to HEX, it results black, which is not the color I actually see on the gridview for that cell.

Comment: It will return 0 if no back colour has been set. Have you defined a back colour for the cell?

Comment: Yes, in gridview's CellFormatting event, I paint some of its cells with a different color, based on some conditions.  Example : e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gold;

Comment: Did some testing myself, it appears that setting the style through e.CellStyle.BackColor will not updated Cells.Style.BackColor. Perhaps you should update it using gridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;?